# NSNumberFormatter for Cocoa-touch?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios

I need to display a NSNumberField that only accepts numbers. Is there some Cocoa-touch equivalent of NSNumberFormatter? If yes, how do I access it (see screenshot below)?

[image]

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to do is supported by Cocoa Touch. However, it won't be very hard to deal with this yourself, please see the delegate methods of `UITextField` (or `ValueChanged` event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[NSNumberFormatter is part of Cocoa Touch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, as I can't find it on Interface Builder (see above).

Comment: Ah, sorry, no, it's not there for the nifty automatic addition. You can still use it by attaching the textField's `Editing Changed` event and then using the NSNumberFormatter on the sender's `.text` property.